# Using N2 machine types in GKE - (Google Kubernetes Engine)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to create a cluster based on a single node with a machine type of `n2-highcpu-2` with location`europe-west3-a`. While I'm creating the node I am getting this error message:

> Insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "N2_CPUS":
>   request requires '2.0' and is short '2.0'. the project has a quota of
>   '0.0' with '0.0' available. View and manage quotas at
>   https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?usage=USED&project=gordion-project.

I am requesting an increase of quota via The quota page (See Appendix-1 below).
Later I am always getting the following mail from google and I can't increase the quota:

> Hello,
>   We attempted to adjust the quota for your project: gordion-project but
>   did  not find any changes that needed to be made. This could be due to
>   being unable  to fulfill part of the request. If you would like to
>   reduce your quota, please reply to this message and a support
>   representative will get back to you. If  the current values are still
>   insufficient, please file a new request with a  reduced ask or
>   additional justification. To verify current quota, please navigate to
>   https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?project=xx-xx
>   .
>
> Best regards and happy computing!
>
> Sincerely, Cloud Platform Support

What Else Can I do to create the cluster with n2 machine type?

**Appendix-1**
[image]

**EDIT 1:**

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

I ran the command in the CLI: `gcloud container clusters create "test-cluster-1" --zone "europe-west1-b" --machine-type "n2-highcpu-2"`

Got the following output:

```
WARNING: In June 2019, node auto-upgrade will be enabled by default for newly created clusters and node pools. To disable it, use the `--no-enable-autoupgrade` flag.
WARNING: Starting in 1.12, new clusters will have basic authentication disabled by default. Basic authentication can be enabled (or disabled) manually using the `--[no-]enable-basic-auth` flag.
WARNING: Starting in 1.12, new clusters will not have a client certificate issued. You can manually enable (or disable) the issuance of the client certificate using the `--[no-]issue-client-certificate` flag.
WARNING: Starting in 1.12, default node pools in new clusters will have their legacy Compute Engine instance metadata endpoints disabled by default. To create a cluster with legacy instance metadata endpoints disabled in the default node pool, run `clusters create` with the flag `--metadata disable-legacy-endpoints=true`.
WARNING: The Pod address range limits the maximum size of the cluster. Please refer to https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/flexible-pod-cidr to learn how to optimize IP address allocation.
This will enable the autorepair feature for nodes. Please see https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/node-auto-repair for more information on node autorepairs.
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=403, message=Insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "N2_CPUS": request requires '6.0' and is short '6.0'. project has a quota of '0.0' with '0.0' available. View and manage quotas at https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?usage=USED&project=gordion-project.
```

Comment: Do you have any other machines created in this specific region? The reason for it might be that your quota has been exceeded. Did you try to create in different region? Are you using free trial account or is it organization account- the quota might be defined by organization.

Comment: No other machines in this area. No trial account. I have a project with an organization I created and inserted my credit card also.

Answer (score 2):

This error means that **you are encountered with the temporary resource stock-out issue at that particular zone** `europe-west3-a`. I've tried to follow your steps on my project and I've got the same error.

**The recommended workaround** is to try a different zone or check that particular zone later. Have a look at the documentation [Regions and Zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones) and try other zone.

I've quickly checked some zones like `europe-west1-b`, `europe-west1-c`, `europe-west2-a`, `europe-west2-c`, `europe-west4-a`, `europe-west4-b`, `europe-west4-c` and found no issues:

```
$ gcloud container clusters create "test-cluster-1" --zone "europe-west4-a" --machine-type "n2-highcpu-2" 
WARNING: Currently VPC-native is not the default mode during cluster creation. In the future, this will become the default mode and can be disabled using `--no-enable-ip-alias` flag. Use `--[no-]enable-ip-alias` flag to suppress this warning.
WARNING: Newly created clusters and node-pools will have node auto-upgrade enabled by default. This can be disabled using the `--no-enable-autoupgrade` flag.
WARNING: Starting with version 1.18, clusters will have shielded GKE nodes by default.
WARNING: Your Pod address range (`--cluster-ipv4-cidr`) can accommodate at most 1008 node(s). 
This will enable the autorepair feature for nodes. Please see https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/node-auto-repair for more information on node autorepairs.
Creating cluster test-cluster-1 in europe-west4-a... Cluster is being health-checked (master is healthy)...done.                  
Created [https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/test-prj/zones/europe-west4-a/clusters/test-cluster-1].
To inspect the contents of your cluster, go to: https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/workload_/gcloud/europe-west4-a/test-cluster-1?project=test-prj
kubeconfig entry generated for test-cluster-1.
NAME            LOCATION        MASTER_VERSION  MASTER_IP     MACHINE_TYPE  NODE_VERSION    NUM_NODES  STATUS
test-cluster-1  europe-west4-a  1.14.10-gke.17  34.90.XX.XX  n2-highcpu-2  1.14.10-gke.17  3          RUNNING
```

I was able to run my tests with my current quota.

**UPDATE** Test for zone `europe-west1-b`:

```
$ gcloud container clusters create "test-cluster-1" --zone "europe-west1-b" --machine-type "n2-highcpu-2"
WARNING: Currently VPC-native is not the default mode during cluster creation. In the future, this will become the default mode and can be disabled using `--no-enable-ip-alias` flag. Use `--[no-]enable-ip-alias` flag to suppress this warning.
WARNING: Newly created clusters and node-pools will have node auto-upgrade enabled by default. This can be disabled using the `--no-enable-autoupgrade` flag.
WARNING: Starting with version 1.18, clusters will have shielded GKE nodes by default.
WARNING: Your Pod address range (`--cluster-ipv4-cidr`) can accommodate at most 1008 node(s). 
This will enable the autorepair feature for nodes. Please see https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/node-auto-repair for more information on node autorepairs.
Creating cluster test-cluster-1 in europe-west1-b... Cluster is being health-checked (master is healthy)...done.                  
Created [https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/test-prj/zones/europe-west1-b/clusters/test-cluster-1].
To inspect the contents of your cluster, go to: https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/workload_/gcloud/europe-west1-b/test-cluster-1?project=test-prj
kubeconfig entry generated for test-cluster-1.
NAME            LOCATION        MASTER_VERSION  MASTER_IP     MACHINE_TYPE  NODE_VERSION    NUM_NODES  STATUS
test-cluster-1  europe-west1-b  1.14.10-gke.17  34.76.XX.XX  n2-highcpu-2  1.14.10-gke.17  3          RUNNING
```

**UPDATE2** Have a look at the error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=403, message=Insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "N2_CPUS": request requires '6.0' and is short '6.0'. project has a quota of '0.0' with '0.0' available. View and manage quotas at https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?usage=USED&project=gordion-project.
```

The main reason of your issue is `Insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "N2_CPUS"`. Try to [request an increase in quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota) again and if you'll get the same reply - contact [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support).

Comment: I tried to create a cluster on `europe-west1-b` with `n2-highcpu-2` ... gone through the same process described in the question, same results. :|

Comment: 1. Please update you question with screenshot of `IAM&Admin` -> `Quotas` -> select `Compute Engine API` and `N2 CPUs` and `europe-west1`, `europe-west2`, `europe-west3`, `europe-west4`. 2. I have no issue with creating cluster in `europe-west1-b`. Have a look at the updated answer and update your question with your commands and outputs.

Comment: Do you still have a problem?

Comment: yes. I have updated the question with the screenshot you requsted. i have also tried `europe-west-1-b` and the same error.

Comment: I can see only the same screenshot that was there yesterday with only one zone. Try to run `gcloud container clusters create "test-cluster-1" --zone "europe-west1-b" --machine-type "n2-highcpu-2"` and share output.

Comment: I ran the command and encountered the same error.  i have added in the question `Edit 1` and `Edit 2`, can you see it? with the outputs

Comment: Yes, I can see your edits now. I've updated my answer.